# TypeError: Math["floor"] is not a function

Tags: javascript, extended-procedures

I'm learning Javascript, so this question may seem ludicrous for most JS coders. I'm reading Javascript: The good parts, and I can't make this piece of code work:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name,func){
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
}
Number.method('integer', function(){
    return Math[ this <0? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
});
document.writeln(Math.floor(3.4)+"");
document.writeln((-10/3).integer());
```

As you probably guessed it, the first document.writeln function displays "3" as it should be, but the second one displays nothing and the error is: "TypeError: Math["floor"] is not a function" althoug it is indeed a function.

I'm pretty sure this is stupid, but I don't find why it doesn't work. Thanks for your time.

Fabien

Comment: Mmmm... it's `ceil` not `ceiling`. Solved.

Comment: Are you sure you get exactly this error? Because the problem is not in 'floor'. Rather in 'ceiling', there's no such method. It should be 'ceil'

Comment: @elclanrs Should be an answer :)

Comment: @SergeyKochetov Yes I'm positive about where the problem was (copied pasted it), but the answers given here solved it.

Comment: This is an errata in The Good Parts book. Wrong method name is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turn 'ceiling' to 'ceil' and it run well, I tested it:

```
Number.method('integer', function(){
    return Math[ this <0? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
});
```

Comment: Indeed it works much better this way. I have the book right in front of me, and there is a mistake in it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"floor" is indeed a Math function. But your code returns the "ceiling" which supposed to be "ceil"